# How can I use pattern to combine data frames using a wildcard?

Tags: r

A series of functions generate varying number of data frames (minimum of 1 and a max of 11).
I'd like to combine them using rbind. If I knew the names, I could easily just `rbind(d1,d2...)` but can't do that since I have to combine a different number of data frames each time.

So `lags=rbind(pattern("lags_2_Y*"))` didn't work.

I can get the list of the generated lag names into a vector like so: `lag_names=ls(pattern="lags_2_Y*")`

If I do: `lags=llply(lag_names,rbind)`, I just get a list with the lag names. I want to rbind the contents of those data frames.

Ideas?

Comment: I put data.frames into a list and "flatten" (final.df <- do.call("rbind", list.of.df)) the list when I need one data.frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
library(plyr)
lags = ldply(lag_names, get)
```

Edit:

If you give `lag_names` names, `ldply()` will add an id column

```
names(lag_names) <- lag_names

lags = ldply(lag_names, get)
```